# unable to install boost on OS X Sierra

Tags: c++, boost

I tried to install boost on OS X sierra by following these steps:

1. downloaded (boost1_64_0.tar.bz2) from http://www.boost.org/users/download/
2. Then to install it 
   `sudo port install libxslt docbook-xsl docbook-xml-4.2`

Then it seemed it didn't work so I ran this

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

and then `brew install boost`

what I got in termianl was :

Pouring boost-1.64.0_1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz

/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.64.0_1: 12,628 files, 395.7MB

so I wasn't sure that if it actually installed or I just downloaded it again! so I found that there are some ways to test if Boost is successfully installed https://tabreziqbal.wordpress.com/2006/03/16/how-to-test-c-boost-installation/

`#include<iostream>`

`#include<boost/any.hpp>`

```
int main()
```

`{`

`boost::any a(5);`

`a = 7.67;`

`std::cout<<boost::any_cast<double>(a)<<std::endl;`

`}`

Anyway, I couldn't run it in xcode and it says  file not found!

what should I do to install boost correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Xcode where to look for the header files and stuff.

In your project go to "Build Settings". You then need to set the header and library search path to `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/bin` respectively.